# html - stretch contents

Tags: html

Is there way to have a page's width and height stretch automatically in HTML without having different css pages for different resolutions.

Just like how flash does it.

What approach should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your widths and heights as `%` rather than `px`.

```
.myDiv { height:100%; width:80%; }
```

Comment: Unless he wants to scale fonts and graphics as well. Perhaps some javascript may help...

Comment: Wouldn't this work with `img` tags too? Obviously this isn't ideal cause it'll pixelate if it's bigger than it should be, but shouldn't it still work?

Comment: Yes, it will if you set all `img` dimensions in percents. And yes, it's not a good idea in my opinion either.

Comment: Yes, I want to scale fonts and images as well. How do I scale fonts? By using em. I just tried it, but it didn't work..hmm

Comment: You could use the font-size:100%; or whatever `%` value, then use jQuery to change the body's font size when the page is resized.